# Symfony : Generating filter+form classes = Fatal error (Allowed memory size exhausted)

Tags: php, symfony1, memory-management, symfony-1.4

I've got this weird error when i try to generate either the filters or the form on my production server.

```
    Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to 
allocate 20 bytes) in /var/www/project/lib/vendor/symfony/ 
lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Core.php on 
line 669
```

I don't know how to get rid of this error,

i tryed :

- Increasing the memory of PHP to 512Mo
- Downloading the entire /lib/ folder and to build forms and filters on local : it went right, i got no error.

**So which files, the generation of filters or forms are dependent** ( apart the /lib/ otherwise i would have got this error on my local computer too but it's not the case.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the memory of the CLI and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be generating your forms and filters, or fiddling with much else, on your production server. Build the site locally, and then upload it to the production server. You should only really be clearing the cache and fixing permissions on the production server, depending on your sfPlugin choices.

The generators are quite a large part of symfony given the complexity of the form modelling it does, so it's quite a large group to identify. You really shouldn't need to worry about it unless you have some heavily locked-down production hosting restrictions.

Comment: The problem is that on my backend, the "edit" pages takes 15 to 20 seconds to load so i'm trying to find the cause : http://yfrog.com/73backendproblemj

Comment: Are these created with the admin generator? If so are the load times 15-20 seconds every time? This seems odd, especially as they are cached.
As to your problem, I'd suggest the 22 calls to the propositions/_form_field partial are the root of the problem - the other similarly large timings are just aggregated from this. I'd start by inspecting this file in the cache.